# CSS failing to load on app engine python/jinja2 guestbook tutorial

Tags: python, css, google-app-engine

Couldn't find anything on Stack Overflow. I've made sure that all my code and file structure is exactly verbatim from the tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles

My site: nathanwjclark.appspot.com

The error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxWIW.png

How can I get my CSS to load correctly?

App.yaml:

```
application: nathanwjclark
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: guestbook.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

index.yaml:

```
indexes:
- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% autoescape true %}
<html>
 <head> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" /> </head>         <body>
    {% for greeting in greetings %}
      {% if greeting.author %}
        <b>{{ greeting.author.nickname() }}</b> wrote:
      {% else %}
       An anonymous person wrote:
      {% endif %}
      <blockquote>{{ greeting.content }}</blockquote>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="/sign?guestbook_name={{ guestbook_name }}" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
    </form>

    <hr>

    <form>Guestbook name:
      <input value="{{ guestbook_name }}" name="guestbook_name">
      <input type="submit" value="switch">
    </form>

    <a href="{{ url|safe }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>

  </body>
</html>
{% endautoescape %}
```

guestbook.py:

```
# [START imports]
import os
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

import jinja2
import webapp2


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)
# [END imports]

DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME = 'default_guestbook'


# We set a parent key on the 'Greetings' to ensure that they are all in the same
# entity group. Queries across the single entity group will be consistent.
# However, the write rate should be limited to ~1/second.

def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME):
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
    return ndb.Key('Guestbook', guestbook_name)


class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual Guestbook entry with author, content, and date."""
    author = ndb.UserProperty()
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


# [START main_page]
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greetings_query = Greeting.query(
            ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

        template_values = {
            'greetings': greetings,
            'guestbook_name': urllib.quote_plus(guestbook_name),
            'url': url,
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
        }

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
# [END main_page]


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        # We set the same parent key on the 'Greeting' to ensure each Greeting
        # is in the same entity group. Queries across the single entity group
        # will be consistent. However, the write rate to a single entity group
        # should be limited to ~1/second.
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = users.get_current_user()

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
        greeting.put()

        query_params = {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}
        self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Credit to Vinnyceptr who found the issue - I had accidentally saved my CSS file as a text file. It was "main.css.txt". I can't answer the question with this since this is a new account.

Answer (score 1):

You mistakenly saved it as main.css.txt and it is served at:

http://nathanwjclark.appspot.com/stylesheets/main.css.txt